# How to reward users if they like a page or follow on twitter on iOS 6

Tags: ios, twitter

I am facing an issues when creating my game for iOS.
I want to reward users with coins if they like my facebook page, follow on twitter or do some other action.

I don't know how to do it and this is getting frustrating.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

One option but you cant guarantee it is put the code to Like your page or Follow on twitter behind a button and on button push you can process the code that adds the coins.

Wether they authenticate and follow through is not verifiable but that would be the only way I could think of doing it.